# Publish Quality of SonarQube Problems

Tags: azure, build, sonarqube

When I started a new Build on Azure DevOps, This build in linked to a SonarQube project I have this error en Azure

### [error][SQ] Task failed with status FAILED

This Error is in Publish Quality Gate Result Task

And when I go to the SonarQube project.

SonarQube shows me the next sentence: **The last analysis has failed:**

If I open to Brackground Tasks and open Show Eror details I have the next error:
-org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException
-java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

This is the full  log:

```
Error Details

org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException: Visit failed for Component {key=Youforce.CloudEnablement.Identity.BrokerClientApplications.CI:BRANCH:sonarQube,type=PROJECT} 
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.UnitTestMeasuresStep.execute(UnitTestMeasuresStep.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:134)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:97)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.withCustomizedThreadName(CeWorkerImpl.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: a measure can be set only once for a specific Component (key=Youforce.CloudEnablement.Identity.BrokerClientApplications.CI:BRANCH:sonarQube), Metric (key=skipped_tests). Use update method
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.measure.MapBasedRawMeasureRepository.add(MapBasedRawMeasureRepository.java:85)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.measure.MeasureRepositoryImpl.add(MeasureRepositoryImpl.java:124)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.addNewMeasure(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:181)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.processLeaf(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:167)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.process(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:142)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.visitProject(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:107)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:96)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:73)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Got the same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: More or less, I had to update sonarQube and after a couple of days it was working again. It isn't a great solutions, I know  @NicholasMayne